# Are there values in IVs for AES-gcm encryption which are just not working?

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

I'm using Openssl EVP to encrypt, decrypt a plaintext with aes-gcm-256. I provide an empty string as additional data and randomly generate the IVs every time using RAND_bytes. My IVs are 16 bytes long. The key is static, just like the plaintext. So the only thing which is different on each run is the IV. If I loop this program 10.000 times it works approximately 82% of the time. Is it possible that some values don't work when included in the IV?

Here are some of the IVs not working: (provided in hex format for readability)

```
868DCDA3B6A47F9461CEFC1CF096E419    
942A3E63CB22BFFCF4309B038575D9DF    
7DABF472A03FCFD4AA88A17BF17049B5    
10E94264C5133011665978290D157FDF    
B33323638D679A4CDD17844C5E50A656    
D77CA61F54374F8AF76BF625F6065317    
A81C1087C2218E29DB5DBBE3DF31CF03    
15678C7484E20DD2C4BDB9E67D4FA7AD    
3DC18C3AAFE48367905091D6C760A2CA    
9940CA7685B92C46F716FE3E3EDD4675    
CA2E9EBACD824F06523A7471ABB1A637    
691D54DB476FF73C27D19B0BFD7191D2    
020FF1C6702BCF5D8715082768B14CC8    
F72623956640DDA62047821E3418F1EC    
743F1B9A8AF46D8EC2472DD44059E87E    
6CC0C96CFEA33DC96B9C8FB27587A6B6    
2A73F05FC73AB2BE0D3B78FD65824100    
0D44B61773986D5C4E11521121A9D7BF    
DEB9896F1EACE3B8F10F980595108578    
4AA5B4922564E664C67BC83B58C18A94    
AFF764905CAD86EF7ABA582853EAD2F5    
FD4C09E91EA36024E8BA8D4D5FA6751E    
5F764A3F0217EAA54D242E28C7E45640    
5ED5B3C23DF30E178517FAB51F28DE32    
34E9B4CF4E2149EBF919F75D9374267A    
31D65E7E61D888CF4C244B009B71117C
```

Of course, there are many more. If someone has a clue I would be very thankful.

```
int successful = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 10001; ++i)
{
    unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"01234567890123456789012345678901";

    /* Message to be encrypted */
    unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char *)"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

    unsigned char ciphertext[128];

    /* Buffer for the decrypted text */
    unsigned char decryptedtext[128];

    /* Buffer for the tag */
    unsigned char tag[16];

    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;

    //initialize random number generator (for IVs)
    int rv = RAND_load_file("/dev/urandom", 32);

    a:
    /* A 128 bit IV */
    size_t iv_len = 16;
    unsigned char iv[iv_len];
    RAND_bytes(iv, sizeof(iv));

    ciphertext_len = gcm_encrypt(plaintext, key, iv, iv_len, ciphertext, tag);

    decryptedtext_len = gcm_decrypt(ciphertext, tag, key, iv, iv_len, decryptedtext);

    if (decryptedtext_len >= 0)
    {
        /* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
        decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';

        ++successful;
        std::string dec(reinterpret_cast<char *>(iv), iv_len);
        //std::cout << (float)successful / i << " " << string_to_hex(dec) << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        //printf("Decryption failed\n");
        std::string dec(reinterpret_cast<char *>(iv), iv_len);
        std::cout << string_to_hex(dec) << "\n";
        goto a;
    }
}

std::cout << (float)successful / 10000 << "\n";
```

The gcm_encrypt and gcm_decrypt functions are similar to the ones used in the documentation. I only changed that the function calculates the lengths itself,

https://wiki.openssl.org/images/0/08/Evp-gcm-encrypt.c

Comment: You appear not to be passing the ciphertext length to your decrypt function, how does it know how much ciphertext there is to decrypt? If you're just using `strlen()` or the like, what happens when the ciphertext contains a `0x00` byte?

Comment: Ok I see, it's easier to just add the length to the ciphertext and then read it and pass it rather than trying to calculate the length. Thanks.

Comment: Does that solve the problem? If so, please post an answer, don't leave the SO users guessing please.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I didn't know I can post answers myself on my Questions. I will mark my answer as a solution once the 16 hours are up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You appear not to be passing the ciphertext length to your decrypt
>   function, how does it know how much ciphertext there is to decrypt? If
>   you're just using strlen() or the like, what happens when the
>   ciphertext contains a 0x00 byte? -- [Iridium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381588/iridium)

This solved my question, thanks.